# Postfix won't run while selinux in enforcing mode

Tags: postfix, selinux

I enabled selinux forcing mode on Fedora 15 , and I was able to get apache, mysql and memcached to work fine , but I couldn't get postfix to run .

I got the following errors :

```
 systemd[1]: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
kernel: [146194.117602] type=1400 audit(1318924444.361:3809): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15447 comm="postfix" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.145456] type=1400 audit(1318924444.389:3810): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15452 comm="master" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.146585] type=1400 audit(1318924444.390:3811): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15452 comm="master" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.390715] type=1400 audit(1318924444.633:3812): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15479 comm="postsuper" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.451670] type=1400 audit(1318924444.694:3813): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15516 comm="postlog" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.459587] type=1400 audit(1318924444.702:3814): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15517 comm="master" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
kernel: [146194.460786] type=1400 audit(1318924444.703:3815): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=15517 comm="master" kmod="net-pf-10" scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_master_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
systemd[1]: PID 15517 read from file /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid does not exist. Your service or init script might be broken.
systemd[1]: postfix.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1
```

following steps were done :

1. I reinstall postfix
2. Created .autorelable and reboot
3. restorecon -R -v /etc/postfix  restorecon -R -v /var/lib/postfix

Can someone tell me what am doing wrong ?

**Update** 
It turns out that we have to disable the ipv6 in the main.cf and these errors were disappear.

THank you

Comment: Can you give more debugging info why Postfix failed to start?

Comment: I have updated the logs that am getting from /var/log/message ?

Comment: This is a bug. Update your system to get the fix. Disabling IPv6 will just cause you more trouble in future.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever need ipv6 enabled, the way to solve this would be to build and install a custom SELinux policy, based on these errors:

```
# grep postfix_master /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m postfixCustom > postfix.te
# checkmodule -M -m -o postfix.mod postfix.te
# semodule_package -m postfix.mod -o postfix.pp 
# semodule -i postfix.pp
```

Comment: Not to mention, report it to Fedora as a bug (which it is).